# Should I use Singleton registrations in Simple Injector?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

In my registry, I'm registering a lot of things as `Singleton`.

I'm doing this because they're all thread safe and have no state.  Therefore, one instance in memory is fine.

I'm also using `AsyncScoped` lifestyles for types that need context/state, but they are few and far-between compared to the amount of singleton registrations that I have.

Is there anything wrong with registering thread safe, stateless types as singleton?

Comment: I would applaud you for it! When you think about it a complete singleton is the most easiest of all. You would not need a container for it, for example. So no IMHO it is as good as it gets with almost all singletons!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a hard question to answer. There are two general [DI Composition Models](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2019/di-composition-models-primer/) you can apply to construct dependency graphs:

- [Closure Composition Model](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2019/closure-composition-model/)
- [Ambient Composition Model](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2019/ambient-composition-model/)

Both models have their pros and cons, but it is only when you apply the Ambient Composition Model holistically that you're able to register your components as Singleton.

I started blogging about these two models [here](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2019/di-composition-models-primer/).